# How to show rows in packs of three in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
ID  Type  Timestamp
1   A     101   
2   A     102
3   B     103
4   B     104   
5   A     105   
6   B     106   
7   A     107
8   A     108
9   B     109   
10  A     110   
11  B     111
12  B     112
...
```

I want to show a result sorted by Type and Timestamp where every 3 rows the Type changes like this:

```
ID  Type  Timestamp
1   A     101
2   A     102
5   A     105
3   B     103
4   B     104
6   B     106
7   A     107
8   A     108
10  A     110
9   B     109
11  B     111
12  B     112
...
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();` and report the result of this query.

Comment: The result is `5.6.43-84.3-log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 
    FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) - 1)/3),
    type, 
    timestamp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c6vWPAXt26kbPNn2weJ1xG/5)**:

```
| id  | type | timestamp |
| --- | ---- | --------- |
| 1   | A    | 101       |
| 2   | A    | 102       |
| 5   | A    | 105       |
| 3   | B    | 103       |
| 4   | B    | 104       |
| 6   | B    | 106       |
| 7   | A    | 107       |
| 8   | A    | 108       |
| 10  | A    | 110       |
| 9   | B    | 109       |
| 11  | B    | 111       |
| 12  | B    | 112       |
```

---

In earlier versions, you can use variables to emulate `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, type, timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        @rn := CASE WHEN @type = type THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END rn,
        @type := type
    FROM 
        mytable t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @type := NULL, @rn := 1) x
    ORDER BY type, timestamp
) x
ORDER BY 
    FLOOR((rn - 1)/3),
    type, 
    timestamp;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c6vWPAXt26kbPNn2weJ1xG/7)**

Comment: Welcome @mechs! That was an interesting question and quite well documented question.